# Psi for riding mountain bike on road

Tags: mountain-bike

I.would like to know what psi should I be maintaining in the tires to ride a mountain bike on normal roads

Thanks

Comment: Generally, for paved-road-only use, you should run a pressure near the top of the range listed on the sidewall.  This gives you the lowest rolling resistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While higher pressure is generally better for road riding, very much depends on the quality of tire. I had a cheap set of Kendas on my BSO. They were rated for 35-65 psi. For my city riding I would pump them to 35, maybe 40. The ride was too harsh beyond that.

I recently got a bike with a sweet set of tires: Maxxis Crossmark and Larsen. They are rated for the same pressure as my Kendas, but the ride quality is vastly superior. At 50 psi they are as comfy as my cheap tires are at 25-30.

I think the difference is that the higher quality tires have thinner walls, which allows them to deflect more easily when under pressure.

I pump my tires to whatever feels right with respect to the terrain I'm riding. I only look at my sidewalls to make sure that the pressure I'm running isn't dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on the tyre, the range of pressures is printed on the sidewall of your tyres. It's your choice what pressure you want - lower pressure is generally more grippy and less bumpy on rough roads, high pressure saves energy. If the road is smooth, go for the upper limit of what is printed on your tyre.